# How to get missing dates between 7 latest rows from database?

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent

I want to get 7 latest rows (***in order*** from down to up), for the current week (Sunday to Saturday), for the current logged in user.

To do this, I used this one method:

```
Carbon::setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY);
Carbon::setWeekEndsAt(Carbon::SATURDAY);
$strikes = UserStrike::where('user_id', $user)->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->latest()->take(7)->get();
$strikes = $strikes->reverse(); //to order the list from DESC to ASC
```

But the problem with this method is that it doesn't get any missing days.

So if there are data like this for the current week (**2020-05-12 is missing**):

```
created_at: 2020-05-10
created_at: 2020-05-11
created_at: 2020-05-13
```

Then for that one day which is missing, there should be a `null` in array. Something like this:

```
$days = ["Sun", "Mon", null, "Wed"];
```

I'm having hard time to find a way to replace missing day with a `null` in array.

If anyone here can help me with this problem please leave your comment. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take data from DB and then create array by iterating on DateTimeInterval(). I don't know Laravel and Carbon well but it could be something like this:

```
Carbon::setWeekStartsAt(Carbon::SUNDAY);
Carbon::setWeekEndsAt(Carbon::SATURDAY);

$start = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$end = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();

$strikes = UserStrike::where('user_id', $user)
  ->whereBetween(
    'created_at', 
    [$start, $end]
  )
  ->latest()
  ->take(7)
  ->get();
$strikes = $strikes->reverse();

$timePeriod = new DatePeriod(
  $start,
  new DateInterval('P1D'),
  $end
 );

$days = []; 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($timePeriod) $i++) {
  $days[$i] = null;
  foreach ($strikes as $strike) {
    if ($strike->created_at->format('Y-m-d') == $timePeriod[$i]->format('Y-m-d') {
      $days[$i] = $strike->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bendar for your answer. But what is ```$checkedDay```?? It seems you didn't define it anywhere else?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $timePeriod[$i] instead of $checkedDay.